# vinyl ftp Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: ftp, gulp, vinyl

I'm getting an error when trying to deploy my stuff with [vinyl ftp].

here's the log:

```
[12:16:46] MLSD  /
[12:16:46] LIST  /httpdocs/config
[12:16:46] LIST  /
[12:16:46] MLSD  /httpdocs/config/Lang
[12:16:46] MKDIR /httpdocs/config
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
```

here's the config:

```
gulp.task('deploy', function () {
    var conn = ftp.create({
        host: 'xxx,
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        parallel: 10,
        log: gutil.log
    });

    var globs = [
        '../' + projectUI + '/config/**'
    ];

    gulp.src(globs, { base: '../' + projectUI, buffer: false })
        .pipe(conn.newer('/httpdocs'))  // only upload newer files 
        .pipe(conn.dest('/httpdocs'))

});
```

As you can see, he tries to create the `config` folder even if it's already there.

The content from the `config` folders are some xml files.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this issue, is that it is case-sensitive. And when it wants to create the folder with a small `c` it throws the error.